# Why doesn't a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass have a delegate property?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Apple provides the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class, and along with it, a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, with methods like

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat`

and

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat`

My understanding is that, by default, a `UICollectionViewController` sets itself as the delegate of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. So I assume `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has a delegate property to be set. But if I subclass it, there is no such thing. Does the default behavior still apply, where the delegate is set automatically? Or am I just misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pay attention you'll see that `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` is also a `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
@protocol UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout <UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

So the `UICollectionView` delegate is also the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` delegate. My guess on how this is implemented is that internally the layout does something like this:

```
let flowDelegate = self.collectionView.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
let minSpace = flowDelegate?.collectionView(self.collection, layout: self, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex: 0)
```

Comment: This is correct although the flow layout also does a typecast, so it's going to be `(self.collectionView.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout)?.<some function>`.

Comment: Thank you! How long did you take you to get a handle on the whole collection view API? I've been trying to wrap my head around custom layouts for a few days now and I feel a bit incompetent.

Comment: I remember watching the WWDC session that introduced it, watch it to get a grasp of things: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/205/. That plus years of fixing problems :) BTW Don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `delegate` property is on the `UICollectionView` (as is the `dataSource`).  A `UICollectionViewController` simply sets itself as the delegate of the collection view it owns, and you can subclass `UICollectionViewController` to implement the delegate methods you need.

Note that `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` inherits from `UICollectionViewDelegate` (which is what the `UICollectionView.delegate` expects) and you can follow that same pattern if you implement your own layout class & protocol.